# Error 504 when sending email with SmtpClient (.Net Core)

Tags: .net-core

I have a web app hosted on AWS cloud composed by a front end (SPA in React.js) and a back end (Web API in .Net Core 3.1).

When I try to send email into a Web API's end point using SmtpClient, the code crashes on the line where I call ConnectAsync method:
await client.ConnectAsync("email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com", 465, true);
without returning any error (does not go into the catch).

After a minute the endpoint responds with code 504 Gateway Time-out.

Would anyone know how can I fix it, please?

Comment: We can't help you, if you don't show us the code, which causes the problem.

Comment: [`SmtpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netcore-3.1) doesn't have a `ConnectAsync` method so we have no idea what your code is actually doing.

Comment: 504 Gateway timeout could be caused by network issues. Try to use tools like `telnet` to diagnose first.

Comment: SmtpClient.ConnectAsync Method: http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Overload_MailKit_Net_Smtp_SmtpClient_ConnectAsync.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by restarting the AWS virtual machine!

I have not posted the code as I thought it was not a code problem and therefore I thought it was not necessary.
However I hope my solution will be useful to anyone else who has had my same problem.